# could I use pyserial instead of pylibftdi in raspberry pi?

Tags: pyserial, libftdi

currently I develop python program in Windows to control PID controller via package "serial", now I need to transfer everything into Raspberry Pi. I noticed "serial" package could not able to connect the device, even I do see "/dev/ttyUSB0". However, I could use "pylibftdi" to connect PID controller in Pi

```
 python -m pylibftdi.examples.list_devices
FTDI:FT232R USB UART:AM00G1GM
```

Is there anyway I still be able to connect the device via "serial" package in Pi? So I do not need to change windows code related with serial port. I am confused by the different device reaction between windows and Pi(linux)